# How do I persist images on Gridview? Please someone

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gridview, android-gallery, android-external-storage

I have the code below which take a list of images which are picked out from Gallery into the GridView layout.
The pictures are shown up in the GridView layout just fine, **but the problem is that these pictures disappear when I close the app or when I pick different pictures from the Gallery.**

Would someone please point me to the right direction?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   GridView gridGallery;
   Handler handler;
   Gallery_Adapter_Activity adapter;

   Button btnGalleryPick;
   Button btnGalleryPickMul;

   String action;
   ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher;
   ImageLoader imageLoader;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    initImageLoader();
    init();
}

private void initImageLoader() {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisc().imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();
    ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder builder = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            this).defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions).memoryCache(
            new WeakMemoryCache());

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = builder.build();
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(config);
}

private void init() {

    handler = new Handler();
    gridGallery = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridGallery);
    gridGallery.setFastScrollEnabled(true);                     
    adapter = new Gallery_Adapter_Activity(getApplicationContext(), imageLoader);
    adapter.setMultiplePick(false);
    gridGallery.setAdapter(adapter);

    viewSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcher);
    viewSwitcher.setDisplayedChild(1);


    Button done_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done);      
    done_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {       
            finish();                           
        }                       
    });


    btnGalleryPickMul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGalleryPickMul);
    btnGalleryPickMul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                               

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {       //Add Images Button OnClickListener
            Intent i = new Intent(Multiple_Pick_Activity.ACTION_MULTIPLE_PICK);
            startActivityForResult(i, 12345);           
        }                           
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (requestCode == result_requestcode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)

{       

SDcardPath_Activity SDcardPath_Class = new SDcardPath_Activity();

String[] ALL_Paths = data.getStringArrayExtra("all_path");

for (String single_path : ALL_Paths) 
{      

    SQ_LITE_DATABASE.addImageFile(single_path);           

}

try { 


ArrayList<SDcardPath_Activity> SQLite_Databse_Data = SQ_LITE_DATABASE.readImageFiles();
SQLite_Databse_Data.add(SDcardPath_Class);

viewSwitcher.setDisplayedChild(0);
adapter.addAll(SQLite_Databse_Data);        

Intent intent = new Intent (Image_MainActivity.this, Image_MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();

  } catch (Exception e) 
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
   return;

  }
 }       
}
```

Edit: posted the working code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put these in your onActivityResult:

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (requestCode == result_requestcode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)

    {       

    SDcardPath_Activity SDcardPath_Class = new SDcardPath_Activity();

    String[] ALL_Paths = data.getStringArrayExtra("all_path");

    for (String single_path : ALL_Paths) 
    {      

        SQ_LITE_DATABASE.addImageFile(single_path);           

    }

 try { 


    ArrayList<SDcardPath_Activity> SQLite_Databse_Data = SQ_LITE_DATABASE.readImageFiles();
    SQLite_Databse_Data.add(SDcardPath_Class);

    viewSwitcher.setDisplayedChild(0);
    adapter.addAll(SQLite_Databse_Data);        

    Intent intent = new Intent (Image_MainActivity.this, Image_MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

   } catch (Exception e) 
   {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;

   }
  }       
 }
```

Comment: I just tried it out and it worked!   I'll mark it as a correct answer, and thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use a `SQlite database` where you can store the images paths.
When taking pictures , save them in the SD card and record their paths in the database.
Everytime you start your activity iterate your database, get all the contents and populate your GridView.
`SharedPreferences` is good if you don't intend to save lots of images.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, but my goal is to let the users pick images from Gallery then show these images into gridview. As I stated above that these images don't stay on gridview when either the app is closed or when the users pick different image/s. I can't seem to figure out a way to save the list (array) of images to somewhere. I printed out the logcat of data from those images, but I'm not sure what they are, paths maybe?

Comment: Hence the reason you need the database. If the user pick up an image, save that image path to the database. This way when you quit your app, the paths are still stored in your database and when you want to start again, get the paths from the database and show the images in your gridview.

Comment: Can you give me some example code please?  I've not done with SQLite Database before and I have no clue how to start it.  In sorry for noob question and thank yoy very much

Comment: Here is a simple tutorial http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/ . Just change the title or author column to file path.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but for me I can't understand how to apply the code to my problem.   Андрей Москвичёв  examples seem to point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a list to remain when app closed, you need to store the list to 
[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), to database or to file.

Method I: using SharedPreferences.

Save selected files to SharedPreferences

```
 // selectedFiles is Set<String> with all your selected files
 Set<String> selectedFiles = new HashSet<String>();

 // TODO put your selected file names into selectedFiles set

 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs_selection", 0);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

 editor.putStringSet("selection", selectedFiles);

 // save
 editor.commit();
```

Restore selected files from SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs_selection", 0);

Set<String> selectedFiles = prefs.getStringSet("selection", null);
if (selectedFiles != null) {
    // TODO put elements of selectedFiles into appropriate your elements
}
```

Method II: using SQLLiteDatabase.

Define class derived from SQLiteOpenHelper.

```
public class ImagesOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image_file";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "imagesdb";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String IMAGES_TABLE_NAME = "images";
    private static final String IMAGES_TABLE_CREATE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + IMAGES_TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            KEY_IMAGE + " TEXT);";

    public ImagesOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(IMAGES_TABLE_CREATE);
    }

    public void addImageFile(String file) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_IMAGE, file);

        getWritableDatabase().insert(IMAGES_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }

    public void readImageFiles() {
        Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().query(IMAGES_TABLE_NAME, new String[] { KEY_IMAGE }, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        try {
            if (!cursor.moveToFirst())
                return ; 

            ArrayList<SDcardPath_Activity> Picture_List = new ArrayList<SDcardPath_Activity>();

            do {
                String file = cursor.getString(0);

                SDcardPath_Activity PICTURE = new SDcardPath_Activity();
                PICTURE.sdcardPath = file;
                Picture_List.add(PICTURE);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            viewSwitcher.setDisplayedChild(0);
            adapter.addAll(Picture_List);
        }
        finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Create object of this class in activity's onCreate.
Call readImageFiles() to read image file paths.
Call addImageFile(String file) to add image file path into your database.

Add after ImageLoader imageLoader line, the following line:

```
ImagesOpenHelper imagesOpenHelper;
```

Add to onCreate

```
imagesOpenHelper = new ImagesOpenHelper(this);
imagesOpenHelper.readImageFiles();
```

In onActivityResult add the following line to the for cycle:

```
imagesOpenHelper.addImageFile(string);
```

Comment: Preferences are not meant for this kind of behavior, the correct way is to use a database. Just because you can does not mean you should.

Comment: As i wrote database can be used too. But, in case, where data is a simple list with a few elements, it's better to use SharedPreferences, instead of database. Database is better when there are many elements and elements are complex.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but the list of images will be long, I'm thinking around 100+ of images depending on the users.  Any example on SQ lite database would be greatly appreciated.  Honestly,  I have no clue how to start with SQLite Database.  Thank you

Comment: Added Method II: using SQLLiteDatabase.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the SQLite example, would you please elaborate about the Call readImageFiles() and Call addImageFile(String file)? I'm sorry I have no clue how.  I just started learning about programming 1-2 months ago.  I know how to pass data using putExtra() and getExtra() or using intent.. but no clue how to call an object in another class :-(  I greatly appreciate for your help.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code.  I added the ImagesOpenHelper class.  I also added the 2nd set of code to the MainActivity class, but it didn't make any difference:  The pictures still disappear whenever the app is closed/exit.  I probably did something wrong, would you please take a look at the updated code in mu question section?   Thanks alot for the help.

Comment: You didn't inserted code into place i marked "TODO make something with file". I inserted it by myself. Try new code.

Comment: I replaced the old code with your new code.  It's force closed on start.  I believe the reason is the MainActivity already has this code:  viewSwitcher.setDisplayedChild(0); and adapter.addAll(Picture_List);  The app works fine when I delete these 2 lines of code in the ImagesOpenHelper classs.  The pictures still disappear when the app is closed/exit.  I've been trying to use putExtra(....) and getExtra() method to pass the data to the MainActivity, but it won't let me for some odd reasons.  I've been trying to find a way all day long, but still no solution :-(

Comment: I can see the SQLite database values such as SQ_single_path : /storage/sdcard/Pictures/2.jpeg when I did System.out.println(" : " + ....);   But I can't find a way to send these data to the MainActivity.   Uggg, this SQLite Database is not easy :-(   I do very appreciate for all your time and help.  Thank you very very much.

Comment: It's really easy. :-) But it's hard enough for me to write app code in Stackover's editor, instead of IDE. :-) I guess it can be caused by viewSwitcher.setDisplayedChild(0); line in readImageFiles. But, it's better if you provide error stacktrace from LogCat.

Comment: I feel like I am so close to my goal, but I can't get thru it.  I've updated the code along with logcat.  As you can see, there is no LAYOUT for SQ_Lite_Database java because there is no  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  so I can't find a way to add the layout to this java.  I think the force close on start is due to the fact that there is no layout in SQ_Lite_Database java, and we tell it to run the pictures on the viewSwitcher.  The pictures still disappear when the app is exit because the MainActivity still displays the pictures based

Comment: on the pictures being picked from the Gallery.  If I can find a way to have the MainActivity java displays the pictures from the SQLite Database instead of the Gallery, the problem would be solved.  I've been trying it by passing the data from SQ_Lite_Database jave to MainActivity all day yesterday, but it won't let me to for some odd reasons... Maybe the data are mismatched or something.  Thanks a lot

Comment: Also, when I did the System.out.println(".... : " + ...); Both SQ_single_path from SQLite_Database.java and single_path from MainActivity.java gave the same result such as /storage/sdcard/Pictures/2.jpeg .... etc.  All I need to do is to pass this SQ_single_path into the MainActivity.java.

Comment: layout required only for UI objects. What's on line 62 in SQLite_Database.java file?

Comment: I just checked it in Eclipse, line 62 is viewSwitcher.setDisplayedChild(0);

Comment: Your viewSwitcher == null. This is because you get viewSwitcher after you call readImageFiles. readImageFiles must be called after all your objects, that are referenced from readImageFiles, are initialized. From where do you call readImageFiles?

Comment: I added the code above.  readImageFiles are initialized in the Oncreate method.   That's all the only place where I put them